# mongoose update a value in a document using model.update

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, database

What am i doing wrong here, I want to update the score?

the problem is it executes the code without errors but doesn't update the score.

```
Team.findOne({name: req.body.team}, function(err, teamData){            
    if(teamData) {
        var a = teamData.score + 1;
        Team.update({name: req.body.team},{$set: {score : a}});
    }
    else {
        console.log(err);
    }
});
```

Comment: please describe what the problem with your code is and if you get any errors include them in your question.

Comment: fixxed it thank you for your comment

Comment: Team.update({name: req.body.team},{$set: {score : a}},console.log); require call back function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Muhammad Ali said, update requires a callback function, that is probably your problem. But there is also an easier way to do this:

```
Team.findOne({name: req.body.team}, function(err, teamData){            
    if(teamData){
        teamData.score += 1
        teamData.save(function(err) {
            if (err) // do something
        });
    }else{
        console.log(err);
    }
});
```